# wordpress : cant access $wp_locale->get_month(9) from a plugin file

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a simple wordpress plugin and I have to invoke $wp_locale->get_month($month) function, but it returns a fatal error

```
function test()
{
    global $wp_locale;
    echo $wp_locale->get_month($month);
}
```

> Error -->   Fatal error: Call to a member function get_month() on a
>   non-object in.....

.

Comment: Do you have access to any other WP functionality in your plugin?

Comment: I think yes, I just started to created a plugin but I am sure I might need $wpdb to get DB values. please note I am a newbie to WP

Comment: Are you able to activate your plugin in WordPress without any errors?

Comment: I am editing an existing plugin, so it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The global is simply not available yet when you're trying to call it.

This works:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    global $wp_locale;
    var_dump( $wp_locale->get_month(2) );
    die();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance of the object:

```
global $wp_locale;  
$wp_locale = new WP_Locale;
```